# Broadcast Receiver using RINGER_MODE_CHANGED

Tags: java, android

I am trying to update and log the changed modes for the ringer into a textview.  Thanks for the Help!

Here is my receiver Manifest: (no permissions required from what I found)

```
    <receiver android:name="RingTypeMainActivity$RingTypeBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am using a Broadcastreceiver inside my Activity as such:  When I run the app nothing gets appended to the `textview` (txtResults).

```
public static class RingTypeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int num = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_RINGER_MODE, -1);

        switch (num) {
        case 0:
            txtResults.append("Mode " +  String.valueOf(num) + " - Normal audio mode: not ringing and no call established.");
            break;

        case 1:
            txtResults.append("Mode " +  String.valueOf(num) + " - Ringing audio mode. An incoming is being signaled.");
            break;

        case 2:
            txtResults.append("Mode " +  String.valueOf(num) + " - In call audio mode. A telephony call is established.");
            break;

        case 3:
            txtResults.append("Mode " +  String.valueOf(num) + " - In communication audio mode. An audio/video chat or VoIP call is established.");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your receiver name is not declared properly in your manifest file.

Change this line of code

```
<receiver android:name="RingTypeMainActivity$RingTypeBroadcastReceiver" >
```

to this

```
<receiver android:name=".RingTypeMainActivity$RingTypeBroadcastReceiver" >
```

Adding a dot (.) before the receiver name is short for your package name.

Comment: I made the changes but still nothing gets appended.  Its almost as If the event is never getting triggered for the `broadcastreceiver` to pick up.

Comment: Try adding a `System.out` in your `onReceive` to see if the the `onReceive` method gets triggerd @John